# Sum of a list in prolog

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I'm reading 'the art of prolog' book and I found an exercise that reads 'Define the relation sum(ListOfIntegers,Sum) which holds if Sum is the sum of the ListOfIntegers, without using any auxiliary predicate' .I came up with this solution:

```
sum([],Sum).
sum([0|Xs], Sum):-sum(Xs, Sum).
sum([s(X)|Xs], Sum):-sum([X|Xs],s(Sum)).
```

Which does not work exactly as I would want it to.

```
?- sum([s(s(0)),s(0),s(s(s(0)))],X).
true ;
false.
```

I was expecting X to be

```
s(s(s(s(s(s(0))))))
```

I thought that the problem is that I have to 'initialize' Sum to 0 in the first 'iteration' but that would be very procedural and unfortunately I'm not quite apt in prolog to make that work.
Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to localize the problem is to first simplify your query:

```
?- sum([0],S).
   true.
?- sum([],S).
   true.
```

Even for those, you get as an answer that *any* `S` will do. Like

```
?- sum([],s(s(0))).
   true.
```

Since `[]` can only be handled by your fact, an error must lie in that very fact.
You stated:

```
sum([], Sum).
```

Which means that the sum of `[]` is just anything. You probably meant 0.

Another error hides in the last rule... After fixing the first error, we get

```
?- sum([0],Sum).
   Sum = 0.
?- sum([s(0)],Sum).
   false.
```

Here, the last clause is responsible. It reads:

```
sum([s(X)|Xs], Sum):-sum([X|Xs],s(Sum)).
```

Recursive rules are relatively tricky to read in Prolog. The simplest way to understand them is to look at the `:-` and realize that this should be an arrow ← (thus a right-to-left arrow) meaning:

> provided, that the goals on the right-hand side are true
>
> ---
>
> we conclude what is found on the left-hand side

So, compared to informal writing, the arrows points into the opposite direction!

For our query, we can consider the following instantiation substituting `Xs` with `[]` and `X` with 0.

```
sum([s(0)| [] ], Sum) :- sum([0| []],s(Sum)).
```

So this rule now reads right-to-left: Provided, `sum([0],s(Sum))` is true, ... However, we do know that only `sum([0],0)` holds, but not that goal. Therefore, this rule never applies! What you intended was rather the opposite:

```
sum([s(X)|Xs], s(Sum)):-sum([X|Xs],Sum).
```

Comment: I never thought that I could tackle my problem that way...Thanks!

Comment: This is not the first Prolog question that took its inspiration from another language. I guess Erlang has spoiled Prolog programmers recently, or it reflects a certain rule thinking. In Erlang one could do without Peano: sum([]) -> 0; sum([X|Y]) -> X+sum(Y). And the left-right declarative reading is blurred, and the '->' is logically confused.

Comment: Prolog II did have `->` in place of `:-` this was about 1980. The intention was to underline the rewrite aspect. Erlang is about 1987.

Answer (score 4):

Your first clause should read

```
sum([], 0).
```

With that change, the vacuous `true` return goes away and you're left with one problem: the third clause reverses the logic of summation. It should be

```
sum([s(X)|Xs], s(Sum)) :- sum([X|Xs], Sum).
```

because the number of `s/1` terms in the left argument to `sum/2` should be equal to the number of them in the right argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really following your logic, what with all the seemingle extraneous `s(X)` structures floating about.

Wouldn't it be easier and simpler to do something like this?

First, define your solution in plain english, thus:

- The sum of an empty list is 0.
- The sum of a non-empty list is obtained by adding the head of the list to the sum of the tail of the list.

From that definition, the prolog follows directly:

```
sum( []     , 0 ) .  % the sum of an empty list is 0.
sum( [X|Xs] , T ) :- % the sum of an non-empty list is obtained by:
  sum( Xs , T1 ) ,   % - first computing the sum of the tail
  T is X + T1        % - and then, adding that the to head of the list
  .                  % Easy!
```

Comment: OP is learning Prolog with "The Art of Prolog", still an excellent choice. And there, in the beginning, s(X)-natural numbers are used.